# File Descriptor flags and functions

Tags: c, posix, flags, file-descriptor

I would like to know what happens with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag when I use the given `file_des` in a function. Does it keep the set flag, or not?

If not, should I reset it inside `function`? Is there any other way?

```
main()
{
    int file_des;

    fcntl(file_des, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK);
    function(file_des);

}

function(int file_des)
{
    //do something with file_des
    //What happens with the O_NONBLOCK flag?
}
```

Comment: The flag is set for the file descriptor - where ever you use it

Comment: Note that `fcntl(file_des, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK);` will set the file descriptors flags to *only* `O_NONBLOCK`, wiping out any other flags.

Comment: Flags stay set until you change them with another `fcntl()`.

Comment: `O_NONBLOCK` should be set with `F_SETFL`, not `F_SETFD`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File descriptors are process-wide. When used in a function, or a thread, they always work the same way. That way is controlled by *status flags*. In Linux, there are [five status flags](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

- `O_APPEND`: Causes all writes to occur at the end of the file, ignoring file position.
- `O_ASYNC`: A signal is generated when read or write is possible; only available for terminals, pseudoterminals, sockets, pipes, and FIFOs. (I do seem to recall it is available also for some character devices, but I have not verified which ones, if any; the man pages do not say.)
- `O_DIRECT`: Skip page cache for I/O. Complicated, with many constraints; do not use except in very limited special circumstances.
- `O_NOATIME`: Do not update last access time.
- `O_NONBLOCK`: Non-blocking I/O. Instead of waiting (blocking) when data is not immediately available, or cannot be immediately sent, return a short count. If nothing can be sent or received, `read()`/`write()` etc. return -1 with `errno == EWOULDBLOCK`.

  `O_NONBLOCK` has no effect on normal files or block devices.

You modify these by setting the new set of status flags using [`fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html), with zero or more flags OR'ed together. (To disable all, use zero.)

The `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, dflags)` sets the set of *file descriptor flags*. Currently, there is only one such flag, `O_CLOEXEC`, which causes the descriptor to be automatically closed when an `execve()` or other exec family of functions succeeds (including `popen()` and all others that fork and execute a new process). `O_CLOEXEC` is normally used as a flag for the `open()` call, though, to avoid the race window against another thread doing a `fork()` in between.

When you use `open(filename, flags)` or `open(filename, flags, mode)`, the `flags` argument is a combination of access mode (`O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`; exactly one must be used), file creation flags (including file descriptor flags), and file status flags, OR'ed together. (Except for `O_ASYNC`, which cannot be specified at `open()` time, and must be set afterwards using `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_ASYNC)`.)